# Remove browser security prompt when visiting HTTPS website

Tags: security, ssl, https

I recently used node.js to create a HTTPS server. The certificate was created free from this website.

http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/

The chrome browser always prompts with a message that the HTTPS website is not secure when using this self-signed certificate. I did some research on the net and it seems that proper certificates cost money. Is it possible to generate a certificate free of charge and accepted by browsers as secure?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

Certificates are generally only trusted when they are signed by a highly-trusted Certificate Authority.  This is what makes SSL Certificates work.  If everyone could sign their own certificates, anyone could claim to be any server they wanted.

To get a (trusted) Certification Authority to sign your certificate, you will generally need to pay.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Would you happen to know approximately how much would a cheap certificate cost?

Comment: It varies greatly and probably isn't really on topic for StackOverflow.  I will say, however, that cheaper isn't always better.  Google search and compare yourself?

Comment: Please check out my answer. There have been new developments.

Answer (score 1):

Good news for you. Go to this website https://letsencrypt.org/. It is in limited mode and offer free certificate.

https://letsencrypt.org/about/

> Let’s Encrypt is a free, automated, and open certificate authority
>   (CA), run for the public’s benefit. Let’s Encrypt is a service
>   provided by the Internet Security Research Group (ISRG).

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by "Cheaper isn't always better."  It will be a very long time before certificates signed by this company are unconditionally trusted.  They will still generate a browser warning (for the time being)...  It's pretty much the same as the site that the OP posted about, except they sign their certificates instead of the site admin.

Comment: Looking at the FAQ, https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/frequently-asked-questions-faq/26, it says the certificate will be trusted by the browser. Where did you get the information that browser warning will still be generated? If so, it is no different from self-signed certificate.

Comment: @LukePark The Let's Encrypt certificate is cross signed with a certificate already trusted by most browsers. (Only Java and Blackberry don't trust it) So you can use the let's encrypt for any website you want without scary warning